# android How to focus textview?

Tags: java, android

How to focus `TextView` on `RelativeLayout` in `HorizontalScrollView` ?
this start not choose
Without focus:
[image]

When I choose number 11 intent to activity focus text 11 on `RelativeLayout` in `HorizontalScrollView`.
With focus:
[image: with focus image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a selector drawable which contains 2 images:- one is normal and one hover and then pass as background to your textview as android:background="@drawable/Selector_textview"

So when you press or click or select the textview the dark background will appear.

Find the below code:- you can replace image by using diffrent colors too.

Selector_textview.xml:-

```
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"><layer-list>
        <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/graph_blue" />

                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"><layer-list>
        <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/graph_blue" />

                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
<item android:state_enabled="false"><layer-list>
        <item android:top="2dp"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/black" />

                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
```